# How can I see all default setting.json in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to see all default setting.json and change it on the spot for test,

but now my settings.json only shows me the custom setting.

For example, I can see only my custom setting what I've set myself, It looks great,

but this has a disadvantage that I can not figure out the options of vscode setting

How can I fix it?

**settings.json**

```
{
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#C6FF00",
    "activityBar.activeBorder": "#C6FF00",
    "list.activeSelectionForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "list.inactiveSelectionForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "list.highlightForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#C6FF0050",
    "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "textLink.foreground": "#C6FF00",
    "progressBar.background": "#C6FF00",
    "pickerGroup.foreground": "#C6FF00",
    "tab.activeBorder": "#C6FF00",
    "notificationLink.foreground": "#C6FF00",
    "editorWidget.resizeBorder": "#C6FF00",
    "editorWidget.border": "#C6FF00",
    "settings.modifiedItemIndicator": "#C6FF00",
    "settings.headerForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "panelTitle.activeBorder": "#C6FF00",
    "breadcrumb.activeSelectionForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "menu.selectionForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "menubar.selectionForeground": "#C6FF00",
    "editor.findMatchBorder": "#C6FF00",
    "selection.background": "#C6FF0040"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.simpleDialog.enable": true,
  "auto-rename-tag.activationOnLanguage": ["html", "xml", "php", "javascript"],
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "window.zoomLevel": 2,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Palenight High Contrast",
  "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
  "sync.gist": "",
  "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "editor.cursorStyle": "block"
}
```

Comment: Also when you type the setting and "" after it like `"editor.multiCursorModifier": ""` intellisense will show you the options plus their description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this stefancho:

1. Just open the default settings in its own tab
2. Change the default view for settings
3. Show settings in 'split view'

#### Opening regularly

- Using command palette, type: `> Preferences: Open Default Settings`
- Assign a keybind to it using the commandId: `workbench.action.openRawDefaultSettings`

#### Default View:

By default, your JSON view will look like the following:
[image: default]

You can change the default layout by using the commandId: `workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings`

> Controls weather opening settings also opens an editor showing all default settings

And now when you use the regular shortcut for settings it will show both:
[image: default view 2]

This effectively opens up another editor by it's side, which allows you to focus it and navigate it with your normal keybinds.

#### Split View

Set the commandId: `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` to true to open settings in split view:

[image: split view]

It's important to note the difference here from the previous option; your settings become a singular tab, as annotated. This means you can't do things like switch to the default editor settings with just keyboard shortcuts, you will have to focus it with a mouse, then you can navigate with the keyboard, but you still can't use shortcuts like collapse blocks. However, this view offers contextual dropdowns that help separate the settings. Either way, you can still search.

Comment: Thanks soulshined!, it works perfectly. and I don't know about command Id, does command id mean just json's key value? such as `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` ?

Comment: Yup! Exactly @stefancho